# Download videos from a list of urls (python3)

Tags: python, video, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a list of urls (sample urls), each of them contains a video:

```
urls = ['https://...live.com/archive/player?live_id=9368953&artist_id=44176&type=1', 'https://...live.com/archive/player?live_id=9344610&artist_id=44176&type=1']
```

Each url has the following inspect element:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='https://...video.net/archive/flv/master/0009368953-44176.flv?Policy=a19_&Key-Pair-Id=PN2'"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For each url, I want to get the link of its **location.href** (in this case, 'https://...video.net/archive/flv/master/0009368953-44176.flv?Policy=a19_&Key-Pair-Id=PN2'), and download the videos from these links.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


lid = [9368953, 9344610]
aid = [44176, 44176]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for x, y in zip(lid, aid):
            r = req.get(url.format(x, y))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.select_one("button.btn.btn-primary")['onclick'].split("'")[1]
            r = req.get(target)

            with open(f"{aid}.flv", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)


main("https://ope.live.com/archive/player?live_id={}&artist_id={}&type=1")
```

Comment: @VNR make sure to copy/paste the recent update on code.

Comment: @VNR well, i see you just speaking about another host than the one you mentioned and then you talking about an issue then the one you've asked for it. anyway use `verify=False`.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη You've an eye for new users ;)

Comment: @CONvid19 :D I should take OSCAR for being patient thought ah :P